# Very low sound, even when I raise the volume on a Realtek ALC882

Tags: 10.10, realtek

I get very low sound in ubuntu 10.10, even when I raise the volume
sound card info:

- Card: HDA Intel
- Chip: Realtek ALC882

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `alsamixer` to tweak different volume levels.

Comment: I tried it . but still the same problem